# React/ GraphQL: Why am I getting an empty array when I search in my application but not in GraphQL playground?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

GraphQL query: This will work in the playground, but not in my application.

```
const countryQuery = gql`
query getQuery($filter: _CountryFilter!) {
  Country(filter: $filter) {
    _id
    name
    capital
    population
    nativeName
  }
}

`
```

pages/search.js

```
export default function Search()
{
   const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ name: 'Hungary' })
   const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_COUNTRY_INFO, {
        variables: { filter },}) 

    if (loading){ 
      return <Loader />;
    }
    if (error) return <p>Error</p>;            

 return (
   <div className="body">
     <h1>
     Get Information
    <br /> about Countries!
  </h1>
  <div className="wrapper">
    <input 
    className="search" 
    type="text" 
    id="search" 
    placeholder='Enter a Country'
    />

    <button 
    className="submit" 
    type="submit" 
    value=" "
    onClick={e => setFilter({ name: e.target.value })}
    onBlur={e => setFilter({ name: e.target.value })} 
    >
        Search
    </button>
    
    { data?.Country?.[0] && <CountryInfo country={data?.Country[0]} /> }        


    </div>
    {/* <h2>Click search to reset</h2> */}
  </div>
 );
}
```

components/queryResults.js

```
import { Card, ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'react-bootstrap'

const CountryInfo = ({country}) => (
 <div> 
   <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{country.name}</Card.Title> 
    </Card.Body>
   <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
    <ListGroupItem>Capital: {country.capital} </ListGroupItem> {' '}
    <ListGroupItem>Population: {country.population}</ListGroupItem>
    <ListGroupItem>Native Name: {country.nativeName}</ListGroupItem>
   </ListGroup>
   </Card>
 </div>
 )

export default CountryInfo;
```

I am creating an app that allows a user to search and get information back about different countries (GraphQL API). However, when I click the submit button I am getting a empty array back. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: ... bad value passed .... use onChange on input to save current value in state ... on button click use this input state value to set filter state .... `console.log( filter)` or check/inspect network request, if `variables` contains good value

Comment: you can delete this question as already resolved (the way I suggested) in next question  ... you should update this question and post comment if further explanation needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please store the value of search input in a separate state and set that state value to filters on click of search button like follows

```
export default function Search() {
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ name: 'Hungary' });
const [formdata, setFormData] = useState({ countryName: '' });
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_COUNTRY_INFO, {
    variables: { filter },
});

const handleChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    setFormData(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
};

if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
}
if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

return (
    <div className="body">
        <h1>
            Get Information
            <br /> about Countries!
        </h1>
        <div className="wrapper">
            <input
                className="search"
                type="text"
                id="search"
                placeholder="Enter a Country"
                value={formdata.countryName}
                name="countryName"
                onChange={handleChange}
            />

            <button
                className="submit"
                onClick={() => {
                    if (formdata.countryName)
                        setFilter(prev => ({ ...prev, name: formdata.countryName }));
                }}
            >
                Search
            </button>

            {data?.Country?.[0] && <CountryInfo country={data?.Country[0]} />}
        </div>
        {/* <h2>Click search to reset</h2> */}
    </div>
);
```

}